# Spring batch to run python code?

Tags: python, spring-batch

Is it possible to use Spring Batch to run Python programs? Jython is not an option (because of dependency on many Python libraries).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `SystemCommandTasklet` allows you to execute any shell command you want including a python script if you'd like.  You can read the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/SystemCommandTasklet.html

Answer (score 0):

You can call the python progam as an executable.

A toy python program to do so is:

```
import java.io.*;
class Interact {

  static public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 python_program.py arg1 arg2");
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
}
```

if python_program.py is the following

```
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__"
     print("my args are",sys.argv[1:])
```

the result should be

```
my args are ['arg1', 'arg2']
```

of course on a more complete program you should read the stderr, check the return code etc...

Comment: This doesn't address executing Python code from Spring Batch.